# JQuery Mobile Tab not loading style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a normal JQuery Mobile Tab Element copied from the documentation in my Homepage. Like following:

```
<div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="tabPersonnel.php" data-ajax="false">Personal</a></li>
            <li><a href="tabServicegroup.php" data-ajax="false">Servicegruppen</a></li>
            <li><a href="tabService.php" data-ajax="false">Service</a></li>
            <li><a href="tabUser.php" data-ajax="false">Benutzer</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the destination file of the a href Elements I want to show some JQuery Mobile textfields but they are displayed in the normal style. 
E.g. code of tabPersonnel.php:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="id">
    <div class="ui-field-contain"><label for="firstname">Vorname:</label><input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname"></div>
    <div class="ui-field-contain"><label for="surname">Nachname:</label><input id="surname" type="text" name="surname"></div>
    <div class="ui-field-contain"><label for="date">Geburtstag:</label><input id="date" type="text" name="birthday"></div>
    <div class="ui-field-contain"><label for="photo">Foto:</label><input id="photo" type="file" name="photo"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="savePersonnel" data-icon="check" data-inline="true" value="Speichern">
</form>
```

When I include the style and javascript files again in the destination files the page is only blinking like it reloads all the time. 
What am I doing it wrong?

Comment: "When I include the style and javascript files again..." You mean you're including the files on the page twice? Don't do that. It may or may not conflict, depending on how the resources are structured, but it's not necessary. Perhaps you could provide a fiddle or StackOverflow code snippet that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I've implemented the style and javascript files again in the tabPersonnel.php again. Because I thought that this is a complete new file. But it is anyway implemented in the main file, isnt it?

Comment: The usual method of implementing tabs would include libraries on the main page and tab content in sub-areas of the page, which means they would be able to access the resources of the main page. However, depending on your implementation, the initialization of your tab content may not properly hook into those resources.